# How do I get rid of PHP 5 in Ubuntu? I have installed 7.0

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, php-7, php-5.5

I am running Ubuntu 14.x on a vagrant box.

I have both an `/etc/php` folder with sub-folders of `7.0` and `7.1`, as well as an `/etc/php5` folder.

When I add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on a working web page, it tells me I am running version 5.5.9.

When I run `php -v` from the command line, it tells me I am running version 7.0.14

I want my webpages (run by Apache2) to use version 7.0 also.  In short, I want to completely remove the directory `/etc/php5` and any reference to it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple versions of PHP can exist together on one machine. This **does not mean** that a webserver, Apache2 in your case, will know which version to run out of the box. **You don't explain how any of those PHP versions were installed. I can only guess but I will explain the basics here.**

PHP can run in conjunction with a web server in several ways but there are 2 main ones (for Apache2):

- run as an Apache module (aka mod-php)
- run under an external Process
  Manager such as PHP-FPM

You can think of these 2 options in the following manner:

- mod-php makes PHP run 'inside' Apache as part of its cycle and
  integrates more tightly with Apache (even to overwrite some Apache
  settings based on certain PHP settings). Everything happens *in the
  same process* here.
- PHP-FPM handles PHP's execution externally to Apache, i.e. *in another process*. Then when the script is done the result is sent
  back to the WebServer.

There are other major differences in the script execution an life cycles depending on how you run it. Generally out of the box installations come with mod-php which is the slower of the two set ups.

I am guessing that's what you have in your case is:
PHP 5.5.9 is installed as a package on your system and Apache2 is configured to tun it as mod-php.
PHP7 & PHP7.1 were installed using another method (package repository OR complided).

**A quick answer to your question:**

No, you cannot just delete `/etc/php5` and remove php5. You can try to remove it with with `apt-get remove php5` however this may require removing other packets that you need for e.g. apache. This reverse-dependency exists because Apache2 requires PHP as an installation dependency. (This may not be the case on Ubuntu but I am mentioning it as a precaution)

**What you basically have to do:**

You have to configure Apache2 to know about the other PHP versions and run one of them for your site. Generally the webserver can execute only one PHP versions per website/virtualhost. More exotic set-up options do exist but I do not encourage running one part of your site with one PHP version and a second part with another.

**What you actually have to do:**

You need to configure PHP7 to run in Apache2 with PHP-FPM. There are many guides on the net and this question has been answered many time here on SO.

[Here is a link I found for your Ubuntu version](http://howtoistart.com/install-and-configure-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-14-04). The description given there  looks good to me.

Hope I helped, Cheers!